# Expected value in binary sequences

Tags: probability, random-variables

I came across this question and I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Let C be the probability space of all the n-term sequences of 0s and
1s. Define a random variable f s.t ∀s ∈ C : f(s) = number of 1s in s.
Determine the expected value of f.

Thanks!

Comment: A probaility space consists of the sample space, the events, and the probability measure.  This defines the sample space ($\{0,1\}^n$), and we may as well use the powerset as the events (why not?), but the probability measure is undefined.  Shall we assume no bias (ie uniform over the sample space)?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $C=(\{0,1\}^n, \mathcal P(\{0,1\}^n), \mathsf P)$  where $\forall s\in \{0,1\}^n:\mathsf P(s)= 2^{-n}$ ie: all outcomes in the sample space are equally probable.

Define $f_k(s)$ as $f_k(s):=\begin{cases} 1 &:& \mbox{digit `$1$` is in position $k$ of string $s$}\\0 &:& \mbox{elsewise}\end{cases}$

What is $\mathsf P\{f_k(s)=1\}$ and thus $\mathsf E(f_k(s))$ for any $k\in\{1,...,n\}$ ?

Then, since $f(s)) ~=~ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n f_k(s)$, evaluate $\mathsf E(f(s))$ using the Linearity of Expectation.

Comment: =n/2. Yup. Got it! Thanks a lot.